# Escape sequence even if pattern not found

Tags: awk, gawk

I have been happily using the following code to get data out of my files

```
for i in 16 32 64
do
   size=$i
   printf "%d " ${size}
   awk -v pat="$size" '$0 ~ pat {printf "%f \n",$5}' $file
done
```

however I've noticed that if `$5` is not found `\n` is not printed and I would like to have an escape sequence even if `$5` is not found.
An input example would be

```
 #bytes #repetitions  t_min[usec]  t_max[usec]  t_avg[usec]
            0         1000         0.04         0.09         0.06
            1         1000         0.15         1.22         0.47
            2         1000         0.16         1.25         0.49
            4         1000         0.16         1.25         0.47
            8         1000         0.16         1.30         0.49
           16         1000         0.16         1.33         0.51
           32         1000         0.17         1.40         0.53
           64         1000         0.19         1.43         0.54
          128         1000         0.18         1.56         0.59
          256         1000         0.27         1.72         0.68
          512         1000         0.25         1.91         0.73
         1024         1000         0.32         2.53         0.90
         2048         1000         0.38         3.98         1.42
```

An output example when `$5` is found looks like:

```
16 0.51
32 0.53
64 0.54
```

if one of the values in `$5` is not present (32 for instance), I would like to see

```
16 0.51
32 
64 0.54
```

Comment: Give a reproducible example.

Comment: @user31264 I have reformulated my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Still not clear. If your $file is the example you provided, then the input should be exactly as it is.  Why should the number 0.53 after 32 be missing?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the phrase "one of the values in $5 is not present (32 for instance)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, efficient, and robust - throw away your shell loop and just use:

```
awk -v r='16 32 64' '
BEGIN {
    split(r,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        reps[tmp[i]]
    }
}
$1 in reps { print $1, $5 }
' "$file"
```